# How can I call another object's function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

In the code below, I want to use One's reference to Two to call its saySomething() function. When I try it this way, I get this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: other is not defined.

How can I change my code to make it work?

```js
class One
{
 constructor (other)
 {
  this.other = other;
 }
    
 doSomething ()
 {
  this.other.saySomething();
 }
}
   
class Two
{
 saySometing ()
 {
  console.log("hi");
 }
}
   
const t = new Two();
   
const o = new One(t);
   
o.doSomething();
```

Comment: If you  fix the typo `saySometing` this works fine.

Comment: typo mistake saySomething()

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in your `saySometing()` declaration. It should be `saySomething()`.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure what would be the best pattern with JavaScript classes but prototypes (which is what classes use under the hood anyway) will allow you to do so:

```js
var One = function() {
  Two.prototype.saySomething();
}

One.prototype = {
    
}

var Two = function() {
 
}

Two.prototype = {
  saySometing: function() {
    console.log("hi");
  }
}

const t = new One();
```